# How can I mimic my OS X workflow on Windows 7?

Tags: linux, windows, macos

I initially switched from Windows to OS X because I didn't understand SSH enough to reliably solve that problem in my Windows env.

Since then, I've come to prefer the following from OS X:

- Keyboard mapping
- oh-my-zsh CLI
- Alfred

I'd like to replicate my OS X development environment on my Windows 7 PC as closely as possible, preferably to include the advantages offered by the above preferences.

My workflow includes the use of VirtualBox + Vagrant (Linux boxes) Git, and CLI > GUI.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like mainly you want a *nix style command line on Windows. You should give Cygwin a try then. It (basically) gives you just that (plus the ability to compile POSIX source to run on a Windows machine).

If you use Git more than anything else on the command line, you can just use Git-Bash (http://msysgit.github.io/).

You can use Launchy as a direct replacement for Alfred.

Keyboard mapping... I'm not sure. You can just search for a keyboard mapper for Windows (I found this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx with a quick search).